# What to write on index page for "product name"

Tags: website-design, gui-design, product-design

I'm developing a product and for that I've developed a website but I'm confused about how to present it's name on main page, I've different options in mind like "ABC's product" or "Product of ABC" etc but not sure which will be more suitable. Also, where to and how to place this name ? would a logo be suitable or simply a text ? Thanks

Comment: This may vary from person-to-person and maybe be primarily opinion-based.

Comment: Yes I understand but just trying to figure out more optimal way in term of UX.

Comment: The optimal way can only be determined by asking your users. There isn't an objective answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

It's really subjective, there's no 'right' way.

What you would do is make the variants you want, then A/B test to see if conversion shifts for any particular phrase/logo only/text only etc.

Also, there's putting the designs in front of people and asking their thoughts. Tools like [usabilityhub.com](http://usabilityhub.com) could help with that.

Also market research, surveys maybe. Or print out the designs, take them to a cafe and ask people - you may find everyone hates your preferred option, or will give you ideas you hadn't thought of.